# HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded with url: (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: request, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I having this issue on my Cloud Run Instance where I use python request library to post request an API however I keep getting this error and occasionally getting success.

What I understand from what I read online is its happening due to Cloud Run closing connections in the middle of a communication because there are too many open sockets.

Here is the error:

```
Error occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.serper.dev', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Her is the request function:

```
def serper_search(self, arguments):
        query = arguments["q"]
        url = "https://google.serper.dev/search"
        payload = json.dumps({"q": query})
        headers = {
            'X-API-KEY': self.api_key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        try:
            response = requests.request(
                "POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            # Will raise an HTTPError if the HTTP request returned an unsuccessful status code
            response.raise_for_status()


            # Parse the response and make it ready 
            parsed_response = self.parse_response(response, number_of_results=3)
            return parsed_response  # Assuming the response content is in JSON format
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_err:
            logger.error(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
            return None
```

Here is the function that calls that function in fastapi main.py:

```
@app.post("/message", tags=["Main"])
async def handle_message(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, message):
    background_tasks.add_task(
        serper_search,message)
    return {"success": True}
```

I am giving this because I want you to remember that we use background_tasks which is problematic in fastapi.

I don't get any error when I run my code in local `uvicorn` but only in Cloud Run.

I tried to add `verify=False` to my post request --> didnt help.

I tried to do it without bakcground*tasks couldnt get the error. -->* This doesnt mean because background_tasks directly causing an error but rather it might help to exceed maximum connection.

Comment: No, the key issue is the SSL error, which probably means you need a client certificate. The retries are automatic @Giacomo1968

Comment: As per this [Github Link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/1356), it seems to be an open issue. You may add your concern to the same issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "Max retries exceeded" is definetly not the issue but the result.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I already have the latest comment in the opened issue.

Comment: @user207421 yes, however this is all done by probably Cloud Run and I don't seem to have a direct access to change this.